# Asynchronous recyclerview inside a recyclerview

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-recyclerview

My products are stored in a elasticsearch database. All those products have a category level 1 (for example Sport) and a category level 2 (for example Football).

I'd like to bucket all those categories level 2 by their respective category level 1 to have this kind of output:

```
Category 1
Category 1_1
category 1_2

Category 2
category 2_1
Category 2_2

...

Category n
Category n_1
Category n_2
```

To do so, I'm first running a query to get a list of all the distinct category level 1 which I'm storing in a JSON ARRAY categoryLevelOne, with this data I'm filling a recycler view named CategoryLevelOneRecyclerViewAdapter:

```
RecyclerView CategoryLevelOneRecyclerViewAdapter = view.findViewById(R.id.rvCategoryLevelOne);
CategoryLevelOneRecyclerViewAdapter.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
adapterCategoryLevelOne = new CategoryLevelOneRecyclerViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), categoryLevelOne, mIdShop);
CategoryLevelOneRecyclerViewAdapter.setAdapter(adapterCategoryLevelOne);
```

On the onBindViewHolder for each of those categories level 1 I'm running a new query to get all the category level 2 belonging to this very category level1 and I'm filling a new recyclerview named CategoryLevelTwoRecyclerViewAdapter:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryLevelOneRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ViewHolder holderTemp = holder;
        String currentCategoryLevelOne = null;
        try {

            currentCategoryLevelOne = mCategoryLevelOne.getString(position);

            String query = "some elasticsearch query to get the corresponding categories level 2";
            String endPoint = "some elasticsearch endpoing";

            final String finalCurrentCategoryLevelOne = currentCategoryLevelOne;
            NetworkManager.getInstance().GetElasticSearchData(query, endPoint, new VolleyListener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void getResult(String result)
                {
                    if (!result.isEmpty()) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray JSONresult = new JSONArray(result);

                            holderTemp.textViewCategoryName.setText(finalCurrentCategoryLevelOne);
                            RecyclerView.LayoutManager gridCategory = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                            CategoryLevelTwoRecyclerViewAdapter.setLayoutManager(gridCategory);
                            CategoryLevelTwoRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new CategoryLevelTwoRecyclerViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), JSONresult);

                            CategoryLevelTwoRecyclerViewAdapter.setAdapter(adapter);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I guess because the call on elasticsearch is asynchronous, only the last category level 1 get to be filled by some categories level 2 (which don't even belongs to it)

[image]

and when I scroll down they all get filled but the order is not respected (categories level 2 that should belong category 1_1 end up in category 1_5 for example)

[image]

Comment: “On the onBindViewHolder for each of those categories level 1 I'm running a new query” Stop right there. This is the wrong abstraction. OnBindViewHolder is a chance for you to bind data to a viewHolder so your adapter can supply your RecyclerView with… views, not to make database requests. Separate your concerns, have some form of class responsible for talking to your DB/Server/Backend/Etc., then spitting UI notifications once done.

Comment: You should use a `ListAdapter` in your RecyclerView, with proper DiffUtil or AsyncDiffUtil to handle new data, but all you need to do is `submitList(your newly composed list)` and so forth. RecyclerView/Adapter/ViewHolder are complicated enough and have enough responsibilities by design, to expect those classes to also manage your network/DB request, data mapping, and any other stuff you want to do with it. What if you need sorting? Who do you think should do that? I hope your answer was not the adapter! :)